# Git Tips and Tricks : Display Branch on Command Prompt not working and created side effects of git branch function not working and many others

Tags: git

Just trying to enchance my knowledge of git and use to tips and tricks,

I updated my .bashrc file as suggested in [Tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347901/what-are-your-favorite-git-features-or-tricks/583587#583587) `PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '`
 but to my surprise now my git branch command is not working and even if I remove it from .bashrc than also it is not working for me.

Also every time, I use my command prompt I get `-bash: __git_ps1: command not found` any guidance or suggestions ?

**Update** : I want to get rid of it now, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you enabled the [git bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) functions?  You may find them on your system already, just not enabled.

To work out whether they're on or not, type `git`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> -- If you get a list of files, you don't have completion, if you get a list of commands, you do (and your prompt should work).

Update: Once you've removed the line from your .bashrc, the issues you've been experiencing should go away once you've restarted your shell.  Merely re-sourcing the file won't help, as it doesn't un-set the prompt variable (and in any case, that variable did have a value before you overrode it).

Comment: Yes, you need to source Git's bash-completion file in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

By googling for "__git_ps1", I found [the first result](http://asemanfar.com/Current-Git-Branch-in-Bash-Prompt) which says:

> There is already a function to do this in the git distribution. If you check out the source
>   there is a directory called contrib which has a bash completion file that gives you a 
>   __git_ps1 function.

So sounds like you need to go find that contrib/ file and source it in your bash profile!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mac try this

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install git-core +bash_completion
then 
cd /private/etc/
sudo vi bashrc
and add the next
source /opt/local/share/doc/git-core/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
   . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi

export PS1='\w $(__git_ps1 "\[\e[31m\]:%s")\[\e[0m\] > '
```

Comment: a bit more thorough explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1):

i think recent versions of git split off the prompt functions from git-completion.bash into a separate prompt.sh file... i had to add a source line to my bash profile to include that prompt file, and only then did i get rid of the __git_ps1 not found complaint.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me 
Just go to your bash profile vi ~/bash_profile
and paste this

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w - \$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```