# Displaying git branch name in prompt does not work in screen

Tags: git, ubuntu

I updated my .bashrc file as follows:

```bash
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$'
```

It works just find and I can see my branch name in the prompt. However,when I run "screen" , I get

> "-bash: __git_ps1: command not found"

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Have a look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231214/git-tips-and-tricks-display-branch-on-command-prompt-not-working-and-created-s

Answer (score 29):

[This blog post](http://velomatrix.net/2011/01/04/show-the-current-git-branch-in-your-bash-prompt/) explains that you have to add the line `source /etc/bash_completion.d/git` before you can use `__git_ps1`.

Here is the full example:

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git  
export PS1='\w$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '
```

This also enables auto completion for branches.

Using that formatting, your prompt will resemble (without colouring):

```
~/my-repo(master) >
```

Comment: how do you do that but still retain the normal prompt information? (ie. just append the respective name)

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.04, it seems that you have to source `/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt` (which in turn sources `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`) instead of  `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` . (You might have to look around for the correct completion file to source...)

Comment: __git_ps1 was moved out of git-completion. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871094/551045 for more information

Comment: @michael_n, that also works for Ubuntu 14.04! Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

I find it cleaner to modify the existing prompt instead of defining a new one. The following snippet adds the git branch name to the existing prompt (which is $PS1). You can add the following snippet to the **~/.bashrc** file:

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git (for Ubuntu 12.04 or less)
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt (for Ubuntu 13.04 and higher)
PS1=$PS1'$(__git_ps1 "(%s) ")'
```

If you want to have the branch name in color you can do that too:
For example, the color green is defined as [\e[0;32m]. We add this to the inside string of the git_ps1 function and reset the color using \e[0m afterwards. The escaped brackets are required to indicate that "special" characters are inserted.

```
PS1=$PS1'$(__git_ps1 "\[\e[0;32m\](%s) \[\e[0m\]")'
```

Many other color definitions [can be found here](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that bash needs to be run as a login shell for this function to be available in the default cygwin setup. If you run `bash` in a cygwin bash you will have the same problem. To set screen to run bash in login mode, add this line to your ~/.screenrc file:

```
shell -bash
```

Answer (score 7):

```
# Add following line to /.bashrc to show Git branch name in ssh prompt
PS1='\[\033[0;31m\]\w\[\033[0;33m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\e[0m\]$ '
```

`\[\033[0;31m\]` is red

`\[\033[0;33m\]` is yellow

`\[\e[0m\]` is normal

Answer (score 3):

add `source ~/.bash_profile` in `.bashrc`.

Had the same problem and it just worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was tested on debian/ubuntu.

---

1. install `bash-completion` package
2. make sure the following lines exist in your `~/.bashrc` and are not commented out.

---

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
     . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have __git_ps1 you could use

```
git branch --contains HEAD 2>/dev/null
```

It displays the same like __git_ps1.

And if you create an alias like this:

```
alias __git_ps1='git branch --contains HEAD 2>/dev/null'
```

e.g. your prombt you get with this command:

```
$PS1='[\u@\h \W(`__git_ps1`)]\$'
```

or with

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W\[\033[36m\](`__git_ps1`)\[\033[0m\]]\$'
```

if you like colors

Your scripts which use __git_ps1 and you promt will work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
root:~/project#  -> root:~/project(dev)#
```

add the following code to the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```