# Bash Ubuntu for Windows, use colour scheme from Git Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, git-bash

I've reinstalled Ubuntu for Windows on my machine, and I also use Git Bash. Aside from setting up aliases I want to have the terminal (Bash) replicate the same colour scheme that Git Bash uses, along with the branch name in the terminal.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

git for Windows uses the same [`contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) script as [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) does.

So make sure, as explained in "[Displaying git branch name in prompt does not work in screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790448/6309)", to:

- make sure that script is in `/etc/bash_completion.d`
- `source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt` (or at least source it from your `~/.bashrc`: it could be referenced in your `~/.bash_profile`)